# How to bind ngClass with obserable in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-template, angular-pipe

I have a container something like below

```
<mat-sidenav-container 
 [ngClass]="{'sidepanel-opened':
 ((isSidePanelVisible$ | async) as isSidePanelVisible) == true }">
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Want to use the observable variable in other tags, getting an exception as

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Errors during JIT compilation of template for RiskWorkflowComponent: Parser Error: Missing expected ) at column 53 in [{'sidepanel-opened': ((isSidePanelVisible$ | async) as isSidePanelVisible) == true }]
```

Comment: [ngClass]="{'sidepanel-opened': isSidePanelVisible$ | async }"

Comment: You will need to use the `as isSidePanelVisible` in combination with `*ngIf` (either on the mat-sidenav-container or e.g. on a surrounding `ng-container`). There it does work.

Comment: if I put ng-container on top of mat-sidenav, the mat-sidenav never appears

Comment: @SanJaisy: That's because when the observable emits `false`, the `*ngIf` resolves to `*ngIf=false` which would not generate the element in the DOM. You could work around it by enclosing the `async` in an object. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 1):

I usually find it neater to wrap `async` variables in `<ng-container>` tags with `*ngIf` so that they can be reused.

```html
<ng-container 
  *ngIf="{ value: (isSidePanelVisible$ | async) } as isSidePanelVisible"
>
  <mat-sidenav-container 
    [ngClass]="{'sidepanel-opened': isSidePanelVisible.value}"
  >
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</ng-container>
```

If you'd want to dynamically adjust only one class, you could also use the `[class.sidepanel-opened]` variant.

```html
<ng-container 
  *ngIf="{ value: (isSidePanelVisible$ | async) } as isSidePanelVisible"
>
  <mat-sidenav-container [class.sidepanel-opened]="isSidePanelVisible.value">
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</ng-container>
```

1. This also allows one to resue the emissions from the observable. Note that each `async` is an individual subscription.
2. `<ng-container>` are Angular specific tags that are commented out in the final generated DOM, and so don't lead to additional elements in DOM.
3. If the `async` isn't wrapped in an object, i.e. if it's used directly, `*ngIf="(isSidePanelVisible$ | async) as isSidePanelVisible"`, the `<ng-container>` won't be rendered when the observable emits `false` since `*ngIf` directive would resolve to `*ngIf=false`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<mat-sidenav-container [ngClass]="{'sidepanel-opened': (isSidePanelVisible$ | async) === true }">
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: How can I hold the variable, so that I can use it later

Comment: "isSidePanelVisible$" this should be a Subject

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<input #isSidePanelVisible [checked]="isSidePanelVisible$ | async" hidden />
<mat-sidenav-container [ngClass]="{ red: isSidePanelVisible.checked }"></mat-sidenav-container>
```